# Using AsyncTask makes the app slower

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I had this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991513/blank-black-screen-on-app-startup-due-data-downloading) and you suggested to use AsyncTask or Service.
So now i'm using for the first time an AsyncTask class in which i add code for downloading and parsing a JSON file. Here is the code:

```
public class HomePage extends Activity{
    private Database db = new Database(this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

        new DownloadDataFromServer().execute(new String[] { "http://www.example.com/data.json" });
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

    // Async Task Class
    private class DownloadDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomePage.this);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setMax(100);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setTitle("Download JSON");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            dialog.show();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            int count = 0;
            int lenghtOfFile = 0;

            // JSON DOWNLOADING AND PARSING
            SQLiteDatabase dbr = db.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                long id = -1;

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";

                while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());
                SQLiteDatabase dbWrite = db.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                dbr.delete("users", "1", null);

                long total = 0;
                lenghtOfFile = jsonArray.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < lenghtOfFile; i++) {
                    JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    values.put("_id", jObj.optString("id").toString());
                    values.put("city", jObj.optString("city").toString());
                    values.put("name",jObj.optString("name").toString());

                    id = dbWrite.insert("users", null, values);

                    count++;
                    total += count;
                    onProgressUpdate((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                }           
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return lenghtOfFile+"";
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(result) < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result + " users", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

It takes long time to reach 100%, almost 1 minute!
Besides the progress bar hangs on 0% for a while and then it shows only 100%.
What could be the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `onProgressUpdate()` directly. Instead, call `publishProgress()` and that will call `onProgressUpdate()`

Comment: Urrrm, get rid of your `StrictMode` stuff BTW. I'm assuming it was in there previously when you were running your code on the main thread.

Comment: @Squonk good catch! smartmouse, [see the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) about using StrictMode and not leaving it in production releases if you don't know about it.

Comment: You are right, i deleted those 2 rows and it works anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway the main problem is still here: the app loading is very slow and during the waiting the LogCat shows this:
08-12 17:07:46.720: I/Timeline(16921): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41b6f398 time:24548374
08-12 17:08:01.525: I/Timeline(16921): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41b6f398 time:24563177

Comment: what does your `Database` class do? Does it extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: Yes, it extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because each `insert()` makes its own transaction in DB. You have to wrap all your `insert()` invokations in one transaction like this:

```
 dbWrite.beginTransaction();
        try {
           //put all insert() here
            dbWrite.setTransactionSuccessful();

        }catch {
            //Error in between database transaction 
        }finally {
                dbWrite.endTransaction();

        }
```

Good luck with it! :)

Also, you should use [publishPorgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)) method for update ProgressDialog instead invoke `onProgressUpdate` directly

Comment: Before using AsyncTask i made the same operations using a method and i did not have problems with waiting time. So why using AsyncTask, in which i add the same operations, takes all this time? The problem is not each insert() in fact if i add comment to "id = dbWrite.insert("users", null, values);" i get the same problem...

Comment: I was wrong, if i comment insert() the progressbar loads fast. So i apply your hint in my code and now it load at good speed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you explain why it works well? Before using AsyncTask i didn't need this hint, why now i have to use transactions?

Comment: In general, you've already used transaction implicity on each insert() operation. Transaction is rather hard operation for db (open, apply, finish). This way you just create a single transaction. Actually, I don't know why you haven't perfomance problems on UI thread. You must have! For big dataset you do have.

Comment: BTW, more info about transaction you can find out there: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm

Answer (score 1):

To update the progress of the `AsyncTask` you should call the [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)) method.
DON'T call `onPublishProgress` directly.